# Switching pages in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a side menu created using a Drawer Widget and I want to navigate between the pages in the side menu. I am using Navigator.push() to do so, but for some reason, the page won't change.

The items appear in the side menu, but when clicked on, the page remains the same. Does anyone know how I am misusing Navigator.push()?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Grid App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Grip App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, this is the start page!'),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text("Navigation"),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[700]
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("First Page"),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context, 
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: new Text("Second Page"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("You're on the first page!"),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
        body: Text("This is the second page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate the **MaterialApp** with another screen. Simply you can right click on the **Scaffold** widget and select **Extract Widget**. Give the name to your widget and it will extract your code into another stateless widget.

copy paste this code to [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) and run it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Grid App',
      home: NewApp(),
    );
  }
}

class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grip App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello, this is the start page!'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text("Navigation"),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[700]
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("First Page"),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context, 
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Second Page"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("You're on the first page!"),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
        body: Text("This is the second page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
```

---

**Error You are facing**

Your current code gives below error, you can see that in the console too

> Error: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
>   Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
>   The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
>
> ---

You can solve this by taking `MaterialApp` or `Builder`

Answer (score 0):

The Navigator won't work if you're doing in under the MateriaApp context like you are using. Remove MaterialApp widget to main() or make another Widget for That.

Try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Grip App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, this is the start page!'),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text("Navigation"),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[700]
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("First Page"),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context, 
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: new Text("Second Page"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Page"),
      ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("You're on the first page!"),
        ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
        body: Text("This is the second page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Big problem here is using wrong context.

You can't use App context for Navigator. Take a try with `Builder`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Grid App',
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => buildScaffold(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold buildScaffold(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grip App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello, this is the start page!'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text("Navigation"),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[700]),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("First Page"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Second Page"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```